# Which solution is better for passing "this" parameter to javascript event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best approach for passing the `this` parameter of the init function to the change event handler and why?

Option 1 (using that = this).

```
SomeObject.prototype.init = function () {
    var that = this;
    this.$element.change(function () {            
        //do some some things with that.
        that.
    });

};
```

Option 2 (using [event.data](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)).

```
SomeObject.prototype.init = function () {

    this.$element.change({object:this }, function (e) {            
        //do some some things with the event data.
        e.data.object.
    });

};
```

Or another (better) one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho the first one is a bit nicer. A 3rd way (if you can use ECMA5) would be

```
SomeObject.prototype.init = function () {
   this.$element.change(function () {            
       //do some some things with this.
       this.
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: +1 for the first approach. The explanation is that the first option (closure) doesn't clutter the event.data object since you may want to add additional objects in the event.data object in future.

Comment: All the answers gives a good overview of the possibilities. I think I go for the first option as this is for me the most the clean one and therefor mark this one as a answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MartijnB: That's the same what `$.proxy` is doing. I assume it uses `.bind` internally if available. For best compatibility, you should use `$.proxy` (I don't want to depreciate this answer, just want to point it out).

Answer (score 1):

If you want `this` inside the event handler to refer to `this`, of the "parent function", you can use [`$.proxy` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
this.$element.change($.proxy(function (e) {            
    //do some some things with the event data.
}, this));
```

But then you have to access [`event.currentTarget` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) to get a reference to the element the event handler is bound to.

Apart from that, choose whatever makes most sense to you / you feel most comfortable with and be consistent.

Comment: This is my standard approach.  "this" should point to the instance in OO programming and that keeps the pattern with little extra work.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to wrap the function that needs the reference in a function that holds it, like this:

```
this.$element.change(function(parent) {
    return function() {
        // do some things with parent.
    }
}(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that one approach is better than the other. It's just that if I use jQuery in my project, I would use the second pattern as it is provided by the framework.