# Can I use jquery's 'bind' without modifying 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a classical inheritence model for a JavaScript app I am writing, and it relies on having `this` defined to be the current instace of the class that the method is being called on. This works fine.

The problem is that I then try to bind methods of that object in JQuery, and it overwrites `this` to be a JQuery element, which is problematic.

I know the usual way to do this is to just save a copy of `this` right before calling out to `$.bind`, but since I am bindinga method in my class, there is no "right before" I have access to.

I am beggining to give up hope that I will be able to get this style of OOP working with JQuery's callbacks as being too crazy, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which solution is better for passing "this" parameter to javascript event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779749/which-solution-is-better-for-passing-this-parameter-to-javascript-event-handle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `$.proxy()` to change `this`.

```
$('.class').bind('click', $.proxy(function() {
   // `this` is now what `this` is in the outside context.
}), this));
```